# How do you show double quotes in single quotes PHP

Tags: php, string

I have a PHP echo statement:

```
echo "stores[".$row['BarID']."] = [". $row['BarName'] . ", " . $row['Address']. ",". $row['City']. "," . $row['State']. " 0". $row['ZipCode']. "," . $row['PhoneNumber']. ",". $row['Lattitude']. ",".$row['Longitude']. "]". ";<br>";
```

which outputs:

```
stores[0] = [The Ale 'N 'Wich Pub , 246 Hamilton St ,New Brunswick,NJ 08901,732-745-9496 ,40.4964198,-74.4561079];
```

BUT I WOULD LIKE THE OUTPUT IN DOUBLE QUOTES SUCH AS:

```
stores[0]=["The Ale 'N 'Wich Pub", "246 Hamilton St, New Brunswick, NJ 08901", "732-745-9496 Specialty: Sport", "40.4964198", "-74.4561079"];
```

I Have looked at the PHP String Functions Manual on PHP site but still don't understand how i can implement it. Your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keyword you miss is "escaping" (see [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character)). Simplest example:

```
echo "\"";
```

would output:

```
"
```

**EDIT**

Basic explanation is - if you want to put double quote in double quote terminated string you MUST escape it, otherwise you got the syntax error.

Example:

```
echo "foo"bar";
         ^
         +- this terminates your string at that position so remaining bar"
            causes syntax error.
```

To avoid, you need to escape your double quote:

```
echo "foo\"bar";
         ^
         +- this means the NEXT character should be processed AS IS, w/o applying
            any special meaning to it, even if it normally has such. But now, it is
            stripped out of its power and it is just bare double quote.
```

So your (it's part of the string, but you should get the point and do the rest yourself):

```
 echo "stores[".$row['BarID']."] = [". $row['BarName'] . ", " . $row['Address'] .
```

should be:

```
 echo "stores[".$row['BarID']."] = [\"". $row['BarName'] . "\", \"" . $row['Address']. "\"
```

and so on.

Comment: Do you mind if you can show me how it will look like using the example i have in my question. Thanks